# free way to see how site displays on ipad, iphone etc

Tags: ipad, web

Is there any free service that allows me to get screenshots of how the site is diplayed on ipad? I would like to see how my website is diplaed into various devices and browsers so  can see fast if there is any problem on any of them.

Do you know any such service?

Thanks
Ryan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Webkit or XCode Iphone/Ipad emulator. Not sure if they still include the browser in the emulator. The emulator is part of Xcode. Webkit is the same foundation that Mobile Safari is built on.

Comment: Just to be precise, the iOS *simulator* not *emulator* is part of the developer tools. The difference being that emulators focus on exact reproduction of external behavior in contrast to simulators in which an abstract model of a system is being simulated. Also, webkit is probably configured in specific ways when running on iphones/ipad to have sensible sizing, so just looking it up in safari on a mac would probably not give you an accurate picture.